# How to work with Scopes when using Workspaces in TornadoFX?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm using the `Workspace` feature of TornadoFX and I'm trying to make them work with `Scopes`. When I'm starting up the application I need to set some things up and when it is done I start the TornadoFX application and I supply a `Scope` to my first view. After that I want to be able to `dock` other views into my `Workspace` in a new `Scope` but this doesn't work for some reason: the original `View` doesn't get undocked but the new `View` gets docked I just don't see it on the screen. What could be the problem? Here is my code to reproduce the problem:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(TestApp::class.java, *args)
}


class ParentScope : Scope() {
    val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)
}

class ChildScope : Scope() {
    val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)
}

class TestApp : App(Workspace::class) {

    override fun onBeforeShow(view: UIComponent) {
        workspace.dock<ParentView>(ParentScope())
    }
}

class ParentView : View("parent") {

    override val scope = super.scope as ParentScope

    override val root = hbox {
        button("new child") {
            action {
                workspace.dock<ChildView>(ChildScope())
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        logger.info("Docking parent (${scope.id})")
    }

    override fun onUndock() {
        logger.info("Undocking parent (${scope.id})")
    }

}

class ChildView : View("child") {

    override val scope = super.scope as ChildScope

    override val root = hbox {
        text("In child")
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        logger.info("Docking child (${scope.id})")
    }

    override fun onUndock() {
        logger.info("Undocking child (${scope.id})")
    }

}
```

The output after I click thew `new child` button is this:

```
10:56:19.415 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  Test - Docking parent (d202) 
10:56:23.967 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  Test - Docking child (cbc5)
```

What I see is the same `ParentView`. If I click `new child` again the `ChildView` gets undocked and a new `ChildView` gets docked but I still only see the `ParentView`:

```
10:56:31.228 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  Test - Undocking child (cbc5)
10:56:31.228 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  Test - Docking child (1dd8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App` already defines a `Scope` with a corresponding `Workspace` instance, so while your initial `View` is docked in the `Workspace`, your new `ParentScope` defines a new `Workspace` instance. When you dock the `ChildView` into that `Workspace` it does exactly that, but the Workspace in question is not shown on screen.

To remedy this you can override the primary scope of the your application like this:

```
class TestApp : WorkspaceApp(ParentView::class) {
    init {
        scope = ParentScope()
    }
}
```

Notice also that I use the `WorkspaceApp` subclass so I don't need to dock the `ParentView` manually.

While looking at this issue I realized that if you dock a UIComponent into a Workspace, it should assume the Workspace it has been docked in. For that reason, I've committed a fix so that your initial code will work without modification.